# How do I get a samba file name using Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, samba

I want to get file names to be opened with Qt, I'm using the static member function [`getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) of the `QFileDialog` class.

```
const std::string file_name(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName().toStdString());
cout << "File name: " << file_name << endl;
```

It works when opening files that are local but it fails when trying to open files mounted on a SAMBA network, the returned file name is always empty in that case. A minimal example code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/qt5_samba_file_name).

I'm using:

- Qt 5.9.5
- Kubuntu 18.04

Is there anything special I need to do to be able to retrieve SAMBA file names?

Comment: Can you try to do: `qDebug() << QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();` Just to see if it is a string conversion issue, or if it really is caused by SAMBA? (You may need to `#include <QDebug>`)

Comment: It returns an empty string as well! See https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/qt5_samba_file_name/commit/c37d0e45cb5c3c0d59d066744c083adb496946e5